# Sql Query - Sum with conditional partition clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below sql table

```
DECLARE @TESTTABLE TABLE(ID INT, CODE NVARCHAR(5), VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE
VALUES  (1,'C1',3), (2,'C1',4), (3,'C1',2), (4,'C2',4), (5,'C2',5), (6,'C2',7), (7,'C3',1), (8,'C4',3), (9,'C4',8)
SELECT * FROM @TESTTABLE
```

And I need the output would be - Sum over partition by with id and the value should be reset with  code (this is not static and should be anything).

[image]

I have tried this below query but how to reset the value using code.

```
SELECT ID, CODE, VALUE, SUM(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RESULT FROM @TESTTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close.  Just need to include a `partition by`

```
SELECT * 
      ,Result = sum(Value) over (partition by code order by id)
 FROM  @TESTTABLE
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much John.
Oh God, Cure my hangover.